# Ошибка с кодом на Python с библиотекой PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyside2

Имеется данный код на Python:

```
# Импорт библиотек
import os
import sys
from PySide2.QtCore import *
from PySide2.QtGui import *
from PySide2.QtWidgets import *
from pattern_gui import Ui_MainWindow
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate

# Новый экземпляр QApplication
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

Window = QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(Window)
Window.setFixedSize(640, 480)
Window.show()

row = 3
column = 2
ui.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(row, column)

for row in range(ui.tableWidget.rowCount()):
    date_from = QtWidgets.QDateTimeEdit()
    date_from.setDateTime(

        # так
        #            QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 9, 4))
        # или так
        QtCore.QDateTime(QtCore.QDate(2021, 8, 26), QtCore.QTime(15, 0, 0))
    )

    ui.tableWidget.setCellWidget(row, 0, date_from)  # !!!

def buttonLoader():
    rows = ui.tableWidget.rowCount()
    cols = ui.tableWidget.columnCount()
    data = []
    for row in range(rows):
        tmp = []
        for col in range(cols):
            try:
                tmp.append(ui.tableWidget.item(row, col).text())
            except:
                tmp.append('')
        data.append(tmp)

    data_for_word = []
    for i in data: print(i)

    for i in data:
        if i[0] != '':
            data_for_word.append(i)

    data_for_word = []

    for item in data:
        # Проверяем, что хотя бы одно значение в строке не пустое
        # (даст истину, если в item хотя бы один элемент не пустая строка)
        if any(item):
            data_for_word.append({
                "data": item[0],
                "time": item[1],
                "ph": item[2],
                "ph2": item[3],
                "fe": item[4],
                "pm": item[5],
                "co2": item[6],
                "pm2": item[7],
                "pm3": item[8]
            })

    doc = DocxTemplate('Pattern_lke.docx')  # Загрузить шаблон (создать новый документ по шаблону)

    context = {
        'tbl_contents': data_for_word
    }

    doc.render(context)  # Заполнить шаблон по данным из context

    doc.save('table.docx')  # Сохранить в новый файл


ui.pushButton_2.clicked.connect(buttonLoader)


# Закрытие программы
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Но, при его работе вылезает ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\CopyMaster\pattern_log.py", line 21, in <module>
    ui.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(row, column)
NameError: name 'QtWidgets' is not defined
```

Как это исправить?

Comment: т.к. у вас импорт from `PySide2.QtWidgets import *` , то уберите везде `QtWidgets.` . Тоже самое и для `QtCore.`

Comment: Ну либо `from PySide2 import QtWidgets` наверное

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помог комментарий [@CrazyElf](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1325529/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d1%81-%d0%b1%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-pyqt5/1325611#comment2342075_1325529)

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
```